# Smartface or Xamarin for iOS app development in windows

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, smartface.io

I am going to start learning iOS app development. I know android app development (using Android Studio) but the point is **I don't own Mac**.

I googled my problem and many solutions came like

1. Virtual Machine
2. Hackintosh
3. Smartface and Xamarin

First 2 are feasible but I am more into 3rd one....As its easier just to start developing in Windows than emulating MacOS first then start developing

At cross roads now

Please recommend what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Xamarin if you want to be a platform-cross developer, and will develop both Android and iOS App mostly.

Choose Hackintosh if your major is iOS development, and to understand iOS development deeply and originally.

The most important is Just doing it. ;)